# Wait on processes in linux

Tags: c, linux, bash, shell

I am implementing a program that simulates the Linux shell and I have a question regarding the implementation of pipe (an implementation of only one pipe in the command - in example ls | grep )-

My main process A in a pipe command forks and creates process B and waitpid on it. Process B in turn forks again and creates process C - then both B and C use execvp in order to transform into the desired commands. But in this implementation nobody waits on C which should create a zombie process. But the strange thing I don't see any zombies created during my program.
I need some help understanding why - because I also need to generalize the implementation to support any number of pipes in the command which means I am going to have many processes that nobody waits on if I continue with my current implementation - so I need to understand if it's correct and if not (most likely) how to fix it so I can wait not just on B but on C and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Once process B dies, C will be adopted by `init`, and `init` will then `wait()` on it, so C will disappear almost immediately after both it and B have terminated. `init` does this for all orphaned children, precisely to prevent zombie processes from hanging out there in limbo forever.

So you'll only see zombie processes while the parent is still alive. And this makes sense, because the only point in keeping processes in a zombie state is to have somewhere to contain the termination status and such, so the parent can grab them when it's ready. If the parent has exited already, then obviously it doesn't care about that remaining information, so the system can (and will) safely remove that information and the zombie processes which contain it.

Comment: wow "So you'll only see zombie processes while the parent is still alive" .

Answer (score -1):

There will not be any zoombie process in your program .
Zoombie is created when parents is waiting for a process which is already died .
Here in your program once B exit , process C will be adopted by init process .

Note : If process B will exit even before C is exited , then you may not be able to read/write status of the command run by C which may create lot of problem .

Solution : Use vfork instead of fork .Vfork ensure that parent and child will run in order and hence there will no ambiguity .

Comment: I didn't downvote, but probably for the mistakes, too. "Waiting for a process which is already died" is how you get rid of zombie processes, not how you create them. If process B exits before C, then not getting the status of C will not "create a lot of problem" because B obviously didn't need that status or it wouldn't have exited. And `vfork()` is a terrible suggestion at the best of times, but since both B and C will immediately `exec()`, it's downright false to state that they will "run in order".

Comment: Two question @paul : 1) OP is cresting a PIPE to run some command and obviously there are high chances parent will read/write from one end of the PIPE .Your statement "B obviously didn't need that status or it wouldn't have exited" .Just imagine the situation where child is waiting a response(read/write) from parent but has already exited .Similar race condition were occured in POPEN system call which was resolved by using vfork in some libraries .What what what you just said ? vfork will not ensure that they will run in order ?

Comment: @PaulGriffiths : For your explanation about vfork .I am quoting a statement from man pages of vfork . it says "vfork() differs from fork(2) in that the calling thread is suspended
       until the child terminates (either normally, by calling _exit(2), or
       abnormally, after delivery of a fatal signal), or it makes a call to
       execve(2)" .Now imporatant question arise here is ..do u have your own version of vfork() which doesn't make sure parent and child run in order ?or you hacked it .I am shocked .

Comment: @SACHINGOYAL: Did you read what you just posted? `vfork()` will ensure that C runs first until it `exec()`s, which in this case is essentially immediately. After that, the kernel will schedule the two processes as normal, and you are in the normal situation of having no guarantees about which will run when, or which will finish first. This is exactly what `vfork()` (which has been removed from the Single UNIX Specification, by the way) was designed for, to avoid making a copy of the address space for a process which will immediately replace it after an `exec()` call.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths : Yes , I know what I have posted .child will run first untill it exit or call exec() .After exec() call you yourself can sync parent and child .can't you ? POPEN has this flaw .I will soon post a link which will clarify the race condition in POPEN call which eventually resolved by vfork() (because of its ability to  ensure that parent and child will run in order till child calls exec()

Comment: @SACHINGOYAL: Nothing in this question is about "sync[ing] parent and child". None of what you are talking about is relevant.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths: it may not be relevant to you and I am not here to justify my post for some senseless remarks .Facts will remains same , it doesn't matter you know them or not

Comment: You might like to elaborate in more detail to which of the OP's issues using `vfork()` (instead of `fork()`) is the solution to, as well as which kind of ambiguity (between what) is removed.